# WHERE clause on a result of a subquery always returns an empty set

Tags: sql, where-clause, clickhouse

I am calculating a weighted moving average with the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT ts_g as ts, runningAccumulate(tpv) / runningAccumulate(tvol) as vwap
FROM
(
    SELECT ts_g, sumState(pv) tpv, sumState(vol_per_price) tvol
    FROM (
        SELECT ts_g, close * vol_per_price as pv, sum(vol) as vol_per_price
        FROM tablename_here
        WHERE ts >= toDateTime64('2018-02-04 14:30:00.000000', 6, 'UTC')
          AND ts < toDateTime64('2019-02-27 23:59:00.000000', 6, 'UTC')
        GROUP BY toStartOfInterval(ts, INTERVAL 1 minute) AS ts_g, close
        ORDER BY ts_g ASC, close ASC
    )
    GROUP BY ts_g
    ORDER BY ts_g
)
```

Which produces a correct result (first ten rows below):

```
┌──────────────────ts─┬──────vwap─┐
│ 2018-02-05 18:05:00 │ 2742.0000 │
│ 2018-02-05 21:54:00 │ 2706.3333 │
│ 2018-02-05 23:49:00 │ 2686.0000 │
│ 2018-02-05 23:51:00 │ 2675.8500 │
│ 2018-02-06 11:56:00 │ 2664.8750 │
│ 2018-02-06 14:34:00 │ 2660.6071 │
│ 2018-02-06 15:35:00 │ 2658.6562 │
│ 2018-02-07 16:25:00 │ 2667.4722 │
│ 2018-02-09 14:53:00 │ 2663.2250 │
│ 2018-02-16 13:23:00 │ 2671.6590 │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

I would like to SELECT a subset of that response as follows:

```
SELECT ts, vwap
FROM ( original query here )
WHERE ts >= toDateTime64('some start date', 6, 'UTC')
  AND ts < toDateTime64('some end date', 6, 'UTC')
ORDER BY ts
```

However, this always returns `0 rows in set`, even if date range in the WHERE clause is identical or wider than the original one. Am I doing this wrong or is it a bug in clickhouse?

Versions:
`ClickHouse server version 20.6.3.28 (official build).`
`ClickHouse client version 20.6.3.28 (official build).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to compare *DateTime* with *DateTime64* that implicitly leads to apply numerically comparison.

It needs to either explicitly convert *DateTime* to *DateTime64* (that not make sense for minute interval):

```sql
SELECT ts, vwap
FROM ( original query here )
WHERE toDateTime64(ts, 6, 'UTC') >= toDateTime64('some start date', 6, 'UTC')
  AND toDateTime64(ts, 6, 'UTC') < toDateTime64('some end date', 6, 'UTC')
ORDER BY ts
```

or use in WHERE-clause the *DateTime* value:

```sql
SELECT ts, vwap
FROM ( original query here )
WHERE ts >= toDateTime('some start date', 'UTC')
  AND ts < toDateTime('some end date', 'UTC')
ORDER BY ts
```

---

I added the issue [CH: Comparison DateTime64 to DateTime / Date](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/13804) related to the confusing behavior of this comparison.

Comment: That was it, thank you for pointing it out! Regarding the issue you've opened, I think a warning/exception would be best. Technically the behavior is correct, it's just not very obvious.